# Multiple didTransition hooks in route

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Is there a way to have multiple functions that are all called on a route's didTransition event?

Here is an example where the actions.didTransition is run normally, but "someHook" is not: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/hedebigedi/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Is running arbitrary functions even supposed to be possible by using ".on()"?

Have I misunderstood what an event means in this case?

The reason I wanted to do this is because I wanted to make a mixin that would get added to certain routes that would then do some general setup after didTransition, but the routes would also need to do some custom setup as well. I can copy-paste the same bit of code into each route's actions.didTransition, but I'd rahter have it only in one place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work. What would work is `on('init')`, but that is a method not an event, see: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html

To solve your problem do something like this:

```
import CleverMixin from 'path/to/mixin';
import AnotherMixin from 'path/to/mixin';    

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend(CleverMixin, AnotherMixin, {

  model: function() {
    return ['red', 'yellow', 'blue'];
  },

  actions: {
    didTransition: function () {
      // This function will be provided by a mixin
      this.setupStuff();
      // This function will be provided by another mixin
      this.doMoreStuff();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Well I guess having separate function calls to mixins in didTransition is better than nothing. I don't like it, but if there is no other choice....